# How to make slider range date in Angular

Tags: angular, date, ionic-framework, slider, date-range

I tried making a slider range with value date in Angular, when the code ran for the first time, it showed the range that I set in my code, but when I tried sliding it thevalue is always '01-01-1970' As seen in this picture.
[image]

How do I get the value range from the declared min and max date.
This is the code I have now:

thank you :)

.html

```
 <div class="group">
  <p class="header">Created date range</p>
  <ul class="filter-list">
    <li>Range date :{{min | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}} - {{rangeValue | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</li>
  </ul>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-range [(ngModel)]="rangeValue" min="min" max="max" >
    </ion-range>
  </ion-item>
</div>
<hr>
```

.ts

```
 public rangeValue:Date;
 public min: Date ;
  public max: Date ;
  public today: Date = new Date();
  public currentYear: number = this.today.getFullYear()-2;
  public currentMonth: number = this.today.getMonth();
  public currentDay: number = this.today.getDate();

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, 
    public Platform : Platform,
    ) {
      this.Platform.ready().then(() =>{
        this.rangeValue =  new Date(new Date().setDate(14));
        this.min =  new Date(this.currentYear, this.currentMonth, 1);
        this.max = new Date(this.currentYear, this.currentMonth, 31);
      })
  }
```

Comment: I think it is a bad UX to select dates like this. Check this plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ion2-calendar

Comment: @Mustika, I think that ion-range only allow "numbers", so you can use `getTime`, e.g. `this.min=(new Date(this.currentYear, this.currentMonth, 1)).getTime();`

Answer (score 1):

i just set the slider value for the month, not for the date

this is how i do

.ts

```
public ages: any = {
    lower:0,
    upper:3
  };
public fromMonth; toMonth;
  public monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
  ];

 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, 
public Platform : Platform,
private viewCtrl: ViewController,
public dataService: DataServiceProvider,
) {
  this.Platform.ready().then(() =>{
     this.ages = {lower: 2, upper:5};
     this.fromMonth = this.monthNames[parseInt(this.ages.lower)-1];
     this.toMonth = this.monthNames[parseInt(this.ages.upper)-1];
  })
```

}

.html

```
<div class="group">
  <p class="header">Created date range</p>
  <ul class="filter-list">
    <li>2020 {{fromMonth}} 01 - 2020 {{toMonth}} 01</li>
  </ul>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-range dualKnobs="true" pin={true} [(ngModel)]="ages" min="1" max="12" (ionChange)="myMethod(ages)" >
    </ion-range>
  </ion-item>
</div>
```

[image]